# Class template instantiations and universal references

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, forwarding-reference

In a code like this:

```
template<class...> struct pack{};

template<class, class = int>
struct call_t
{
    template<class... args_t>
    static int apply(args_t&&...)
    { return 0; }
};

template<class... args_t>
struct call_t<pack<args_t...>, // (1)
        std::decay_t<decltype(convert(declval<args_t>()...))> >
{
    template<class... params_t> // (2)
    static int apply(params_t&&... args)
    { return convert(std::forward<params_t>(args)...); }
};

template<class... args_t>
auto test(args_t&&... args) // (3)
{
    return call_t<pack<args_t...> >::
       apply(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
}
```

This function sends a pack of params to a function or another according to if a function `convert` exists and can be called with the passed params, keeping intact (I guess) their exact passed types, and when its return type is `int`, irrespective of reference or const qualifiers.

I have three doubts with that piece of code.

- (1) Is `declval` return type still a universal reference? For instance, `declval<T>()`, with `T = int&`, will its return type be `int&&` (a true r-value reference), or `int & &&` and be deduced again as `int&` following the usual rules of universal references when passing to another call? I supposed that it doesn't (as pointed out by @101010), but I don't know in that case how to make a perfect overloading test.
- (2) Do I need to re-specify the variadic template to use the universal reference deduction rules, or since the correct types have been already deduced in (3), they keep their deduced types intact?

Or can I just write

```
template<class... args_t>
struct call_t<pack<args_t...>, // (1)
        std::decay_t<decltype(convert(declval<args_t>()...))> >
{
    // (2)
    static int apply(args_t... args)
    { return convert(args...); }
};
```

?

The `call_t` template class is an implementation detail, so, it will be instantiate only inside `test`.

Comment: Regarding the first question: [`std::decval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)'s return type is `T&&` unless `T` is (possibly cv-qualified) `void`, in which case the return type is `T`.

Comment: So I lose the original types of the passed parameters in (3). The thing is I don't know how to make a perfect "overload test" (in a unevaluated context), or at least don't without involving more extra auxiliary templates.

Comment: No, if `T = int&` for instance, `T&&` is indeed `int&` by reference collapsing rules

Comment: As your code is working, I think this is a question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Ok I will copy-paste it there. Should I close or delete this post?

Comment: I'm just one opinion ;) and not the boss. Maybe just do a second topic (i.e. copy) first. It could be that you get good feedback on this site.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius I don't want to behave like a "troll", posting the same question in different places. My question has two natures, if it will work reliably for any `convert` overload (a question that I think is more closed to StackOverflow, but I have no failed use-case), and if template (2) is redundant (maybe more suitable to CodeReview, because I think it doesn't affect the "semantics" of the intended purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two cases are **not** equivalent. This example:

```
template<class... args_t>
struct call_t<pack<args_t...>, // (1)
        std::decay_t<decltype(convert(declval<args_t>()...))> >
{
    // (2)
    static int apply(args_t... args)
    { return convert(args...); }
};
```

does not forward anything. The parameter pack `args...` are lvalues, because they have names. That is very different than this code:

```
template<class... params_t> // (2)
static int apply(params_t&&... args)
{ return convert(std::forward<params_t>(args)...); }
```

in which `args...` *is* forwarded. The resulting behavior is that the new example could be slower than the old example (doing copies instead of moves) or could simply surprisingly fail to compile. Consider `convert(std::unique_ptr<int> )`. That *is* invocable with `args_t = {std::unique_ptr<int>}`, but the internal `apply()` would fail because you'd be trying to copy the `unique_ptr`.

You'd need to do:

```
static int apply(args_t... args)
{ return convert(std::forward<args_t>(args)...); }
```